# From single linked list to double linked list

Tags: python, list, loops, linked-list, iteration

How can I write a function like 'next(lst)' that returns the PREVIOUS value instead of the NEXT value?

```
class EmptyNode():
    __slots__ = ()

class Node():
    __slots__ = ('data', 'next')


class MyList():
"""A class that encapsulates a node based linked list"""
    __slots__ = ('head', 'size', 'cursor')

def mkEmptyNode():
    return EmptyNode()

def mkNode(data, next):
    node = Node()
    node.data = data
    node.next = next
    return node

def mkMyList():
    lst = MyList()
    lst.head = mkEmptyNode()
    lst.size = 0
    lst.cursor = mkEmptyNode()
    return lst
```

In a linked list similar to `['a','b','c']`, `next(lst)` will return `'a'`, the next time it will return `'b'`, the next time it will return `'c'`, and the next time it will return an error

```
def next(lst):
    if isinstance(lst.cursor, EmptyNode):
        raise IndexError("cursor is invalid")

    val = lst.cursor.data
    lst.cursor = lst.cursor.next
    return val
```

Comment: At what point do you create non-empty nodes? Because your `mkMyList` just creates empty nodes (which don't have a `next` attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to maintain an additional pointer in each list item (`previous`).

```
class EmptyNode():
  __slots__ = ()

class Node():
  __slots__ = ('data', 'next', 'prev')

class MyList():
  """A class that encapsulates a node based linked list"""
  __slots__ = ('head', 'size', 'cursor')

def mkEmptyNode():
  return EmptyNode()

def mkNode(prev, data, next):
  node = Node()
  node.prev = prev
  node.data = data
  node.next = next
  return node

def mkMyList():
  lst = MyList()
  lst.head = mkEmptyNode()
  lst.size = 0
  lst.cursor = mkEmptyNode()
  return lst
```

You can then use it to navigate the list backwards:

```
def previous(lst):
  if isinstance(lst.cursor, EmptyNode):
    raise IndexError("cursor is invalid")

  val = lst.cursor.data
  lst.cursor = lst.cursor.prev
  return val
```

Answer (score 0):

In a regular doubly linked list, you'd add a `prev` attribute to the Node class (pointing to the *previous* node) and add a prev method that does something like:

```
class Node():
    __slots__ = ('data', 'next', 'prev')
```

and then:

```
def prev(lst):
    if isinstance(lst.cursor, EmptyNode):
        raise IndexError("cursor is invalid")

    val = lst.cursor.data
    lst.cursor = lst.cursor.prev
    return val
```